# A matrix with given row and column sums

Tags: linear-algebra

There are a set of equations like

$A_x + A_y + A_z = P$
$B_x + B_y + B_z = Q$
$C_x + C_y + C_z = R$

Where the values of only $P, Q, R$ are known.

Also, 
we have

$A_x + B_x + C_x = I$
$A_y + B_y + C_y = J$
$A_z + B_z + C_z = K$

where only the values of $I, J$ and $K$ are known.

Is there any way we know the individual values of

$A_x, B_x, C_x, A_y, A_z$ and the rest?

Substituting the above equations yield the result that $I + J + K = P + Q + R$ but how can I get the individual component values? Is any other information required to solve these equations?

---

Here's a good complementary question. If solutions exist, how to generate all of them? Are there some algorithms?

Comment: I suppose you mean $P+Q+R=I+J+K$ (there are no $X,Y,Z$ in the equations). This is indeed a necessary condition for the existence of a solution. Supposing that, you've got effectively $5$ linear equations (since one is dependent on the others) in $9$ unknowns; you cannot hope for a unique solution.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks i corrected it I  +J + K = P +Q +R, Also, just now a friend told that there should be 9 equations to solve and get 9 unknow's. I guess that settle's it.

Answer (score 2):

As explained above, the set of acceptable matrices is a finite dimensional linear space $E$. In the other hand, if the margins are positive, the set of matrices $A= (a_{ij})$ with nonegative coefficients  is a compact convex subset $K$ of $E$ whose extreme points are the $A$ such that $S=\{(i,j), a_{i,j}>0\}$ is a subset of  $I\times J$ (where $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $J=\{1,\ldots,m\}$) with the following property: equip the set $I\cup J$ with edges between $I$ and $J$ only such that $(i,j)$ is an edge when $(i,j)\in S.$

Then $A$ is an extreme point of $K$ if and only if the above graph has no cycles.

Comment: Hello Gerard. These are _transportation polytopes_. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895672900603

Comment: Hello, 54 years after the Lions of Vancouver. Apologies , Ethan, I was unable to remember the title of your clever paper. Its reference saves me the task to reconstruct the proof!

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $(\begin{smallmatrix}+1&-1\\-1&+1\end{smallmatrix})$ has all row and column sums zero. So given any matrix$~A$ with at least two rows and at least two columns, you can always add a multiple of this matrix to a $2\times2$ submatrix of $A$ to obtain a different matrix $A'$ with the same row and column sums. So for such matrices, the row and column sums *never* determine the matrix.

Comment: I think we need additional information to solve these equations. I will check.

Answer (score 1):

The rank one m×n matrix `A` is of the form `u⋅v^*` (^* is the conjugate transpose) in which case given the 1×n column margin/sum vector `sc=[1,....,1]⋅A` and the m×1 row margin/sum vector `sr=A⋅[1,....,1]^⊤`.

```
u=sr/√(∑(sr))
v=(sc/√(∑(sc)))^*
A=u⋅v^*=sr⋅sc/∑(sr)
```

As long as there is no division by zero this will work for all other complex valued `u` and `v` vectors.
If the matrix `A` is of rank greater than one then calculation of `u⋅v^*` will give the unique rank one approximation of `A`, in exactly the same way that the singular value decomposition truncated to one non-zero singular value gives the optimal rank one approximation in the sense that it will minimize the sum of absolute value squared errors.

To generate all other solutions you can just generate all matrixes that have all zero row and column sums then add it to the approximate rank one matrix `A`.
One simple algorithm is the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm, it is even easier because we can assume that all satisfying matrixes are of equal probability and so it just devolves into a simple random walk:

```
    metrosample_dual_axes_sum_invariant_matrixes(A){
        raptor_bait:
        new_A=random_walk_adjustment(A);
        if(not is_sample_acceptable(new_A))goto raptor_bait;
        use_the_sample(A=new_A) ??!??! die();
        goto raptor_bait;/*xkcd:292*/
    }
    random_walk_adjustment(z/*cow-reference*/){
        pick "random" matrix coordinates (i,j) and (k,l)∈[1,m]×[1,n]⊂Z²;
        pick "random" offset o∈{a∈ℂ:0<|a|≤1}
        dual_axis_marginal_sum_invariant_Morphizer_XE(&z,o,i,j,k,l);
        return z;
    }
    dual_axis_marginal_sum_invariant_Morphizer_XE(
        &Summer/*Rick and Morty reference*/,offset,i,j,k,l
    ){
        Summer[i,j]+=offest;
        Summer[k,l]+=offest;/*a little more on the other side*/
        Summer[k,j]-=offest;/*a little less on the off axis*/
        Summer[i,l]-=offest;
        /* just an increment of the following scaled row column permuted version of
         * the following submatrix: |  1 -1 |
         *                          | -1  1 |
         */
        return;
    }
    /* for the incompetent code nazis: cow=copy on write */
```

While the sequence of matrixes generated are serially correlated, in the limit the set of generated matrixes will be uniformly distributed.

#### Summary Lessons

Just because the solution space is infinite and over many dimensions:

- does not mean it is difficult to sample from
- does not mean there is not a unique maximum likelihood solution
- does not mean someone will not write code for it while watching Rick and Morty because they woke up in the middle of the night :(: knowing full well that the answer will probably never be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} A_x\\A_y\\A_z\\B_x\\B_y\\B_z\\C_x\\C_y\\C_z
\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} P\\Q\\R\\I\\J\\K \end{matrix}\right)$$
If you have any solution, it will be at least a four*-dimensional solution space, and to have a solution, necessarily the equation $P+Q+R=I+J+K$ must hold, as you already found out.

*If the LHS is $Ax$ then the dimension (if $\ge 0$) is at least $9 - {\rm rg}(A) = 9-5 = 4$, the rank is only five because the sum of the first three rows is equal to the sum of the last three rows.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks for pointing out that the Rank of the $6\times 9$ matrix is only $5$ ;)