# how should i describe this combination of group actions?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

let $A$ be a multiplicative abelian group and let $D_m=D_m(A)$ for integer $m \gt 0$ be the group of $m \times m$ diagonal matrices with entries in $A$. now $D_m$ has a subgroup $A^* \cong A$ which is formed by the "scalar" matrices in which every diagonal component is the same element of A. the factor group $E_m=\frac{D_m}{A^*}$ (which we may call the *co-scalar* matrices) is the subgroup comprising those diagonal matrices for which the product of all the entries is $1_A$.

I want to describe the following situation. $T_{mn}$ is the set of $m \times n$ matrices with elements in $A$.

$T_{mn}$ is acted on by $D_m$ and $D_n$ by multiplication on the right and left. thus $D_m$ acts on rows and $D_n$ acts on columns.

but what really happens is that $T_{mn}$ is acted on by $E_m$ and by $E_n$ (on rows and columns, respectively), and also by a scalar group isomorphic to $A$ which multiplies all elements of $T_{mn}$ by the same element of $A$

QUESTION what is the appropriate description for this? it seems to have something in common with what happens in a tensor product $X \otimes_R Y$ where we have $x \otimes ry = xr \otimes y$, but I have as yet only a rather vague notion of what a tensor product is, and I have not seen the notation used with groups.

I would appreciate any help in gaining a clearer idea of how this really rather simple situation should be properly described.

Comment: Multiplying matrices requires two operations (addition and multiplication) on the scalars, whereas a group only comes equipped with one operation, so your situation is ill-defined.

Comment: not when one of the matrices is a diagonal matrix

Comment: Okay, I suppose you can get an action with only one operation. Next, how is a factor group a subgroup, and what is the action of $E_n=D_n/A^*$ on $T_{mn}$?

Comment: Aren't you making things unnecessarily complicated, in that your $D_m(A)$ is isomorphic to $A^m$, and the subgroup corresponding to the constant diagonals isomorphic to $A$ equally realized as the constant $m$-tuples of $A^m$?

Comment: the group is abelian so the factor group must be a direct summand, usually explained in terms of the splitting of a short exact sequence (via two auxiliary maps represented by arrows in the opposite direction connecting the three central elements of the sequence)

Comment: A factor group need not be a direct summand of an abelian group. And even when it is, there could be more than one choice of subgroup it corresponds to.

Comment: @hardmath, I have no objection to your description, but in the application it makes more sense to describe it as here. basically you project a $T_{mn}$ onto a $T_m$ by taking row sums, then invert the sums (reciprocal) and multiply by a constant. the vector of such products is then used to act  on the rows by multiplication.

Comment: @anon I'd appreciate a reference to a simple explanation of the abelian group question. but definitely in the situation envisaged, you have row multipliers and column multipliers, and the combination is not quite unique because of the scalar ambiguity. basically $\lambda D_1 T D_2 = D_1 T \lambda D_2$.

Comment: What is "the abelian group question"? I don't know what multipliers are, or what you mean by "combination" or "ambiguity" or that equation. Really I don't follow your last two comments at all, they seem totally disparate from the original question.

Comment: as usual I extend my thanks to my anonymous downvoters. they are a key source of motivation, if not of useful information. one day soon, after gathering more records on their modus operandi for the rapidly expanding database, I hope to write a short paper outlining the essential role they play in the teaching and practice of mathematics. it is a tricky task to clearly distinguish the merely sour from the chronically spiteful, and to investigate the roles played by factors like disappointment, envy and chronic dyspepsia in generating their furtive surliness and curmudgeonly attitude

Comment: Or you could devote those energies to writing more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

### Central product

You are correct that you have a tensor product in the matrix sense. The more usual term here is “central product”. You want to mod out by $A^*$, but the $E_m$ way is not quite right.

You have an action of $D_m \times D_n$ where the element $(R,C)$ acts on the matrix $M$ by $RMC$ (where I ignore left/right corrections since $D_m$ and $D_n$ are abelian).

However, this action has a kernel, $K=\left\{ \left( D_m(a), D_n(a^{-1}) \right) : a \in A \right\} \cong A^*$ and you do want to mod out by it. So you want the group $D_m \mathsf{Y} D_n = (D_m \times D_n)/K$.

In GAP, you can use `CentralProductOfMatrixGroups` to form the central product where the amalgamated (squished) part is the scalar matrices. This is used all the time. The function even returns a matrix group, like you'd like. How does it do it?

### Keeping it matrixy

So you probably liked the $E_m$ idea because it maintained your quotient group as a subgroup (not all quotient groups are like this, but this one is). However, you ran into trouble because $E_m \times E_n$ wasn't quite right, and $E_m \times D_n$ probably disturbed your sense of symmetry. Luckily matrix algebra has an old solution for this.

Note that each of these actions of $D_n$ and $D_m$ is linear, so we view the set of all $M$ as a vector space with a basis (the standard basis of nearly 0 matrices $E_{ij}$, in a particular order, probably lexicographic). In this basis the action of $\overline{(R,C)} \in D_m \mathsf{Y} D_n$ is given by a matrix, namely `KroneckerProduct(R,C)` in GAP, and the Kronecker product $R \otimes C$ in mathy land.

Kronecker products are pretty simple to understand: one of the matrices is the "pattern" and the other is the "fill". The pattern matrix decides which multiple of the fill matrix to use. So $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\\5&6\end{bmatrix} \otimes A$ is the block matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A & 2A \\ 3A & 4A \\ 5A & 6A \end{bmatrix}$.

### Application

I don't believe central products or Kronecker products help very much in the application (except that Kronecker products made my code quite a bit shorter). However, I do include one simplification in the below discussion that made it much easier to recognize the “unique” solution, so that the other solutions stand out clearly.

Given an $m \times n$ matrix $X$, an $m \times 1$ matrix $P$, and a $1 \times n$ matrix $Q$, find diagonal matrices $L_{m \times m}$ and $R_{n \times n}$ such that $Q=J_{1\times m} LXR$ and $LXRJ_{n\times 1}=P$, where $J_{a\times b}$ is an $a \times b$ matrix consisting of $1$s. The goal is to show that $L \otimes R$ is uniquely determined if it exists.

If $(L,R)$ and $(L',R')$ are two solutions, set $Y=LXR$. Then $P=JY$ and $YJ=Q$ and $L'XR' = L''YR''$ where $L'' = L' L^{-1}$ and $R''=R^{-1} R'$, so we might as well start with $Y$ for the uniqueness proof. This means the only solution we want is $L \otimes R = 1$ which is a little easier to detect.

The collection $C$ of all $m \times n$ matrices $Y$ such that $P=JY$ and $YJ=Q$ is somewhat large (see [A matrix with given row and column sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546733/a-matrix-with-given-row-and-column-sums) with a hidden kronecker product in it). If $Y,Z \in C$ then $J(Y-Z)=P-P=0$ and $(Y-Z)J=Q-Q=0$, so $C$ is a coset of the space $V$ of all matrices with 0 row and column sums.

The application (in group action language) is to show that the action of $D_m \mathsf{Y} D_n = \{ L \otimes R \}$ has a small setwise stabilizer: if $LXR \in C$ and $L'XR' \in C$, then $L \otimes R = L' \otimes R'$. I don't think this is too useful, other than it doesn't seem incredibly likely to be true.

The algebra for $LXR$ is a bit of a hassle, so we can replace this with Kronecker products. The `vec` operation (`Flat` in GAP) lays out a matrix as a vector. It has the defining property that $vec(LXR) = (L\otimes R)\cdot vec(X)$. So we are trying to solve $((L\otimes R)-1)\cdot vec(Y) = vec(Z)$ for diagonal matrices $L,R$ and a zero row/col sum matrix $Z \in V$. If the only solution is $L \otimes R =1$ and $Z=0$, then this is an affirmative answer; any other answer is an explicit counterexample (though the application required $L$ and $R$ to be positive).

I don't see a great way to solve this. For a specific $Y$, it is a bunch of multivariate quadratic equations which can be handled using the theory of equations. These are the same equations you started with, just slightly cleaned up using $Y$ instead of $X$. I've done a few examples, and there are plenty of counterexamples if you allow $L$ or $R$ to have negative entries. I haven't found any counterexample with both $L$ and $R$ positive.

Comment: If your $A$ really consists of say nonzero complex numbers (or matrices of complex numbers) then you'd probably like Bellman's Introduction to Matrix Analysis where he explains direct sums and kronecker products in a very simple way. Central products are covered in lots of finite group textbooks. Gorenstein's Finite Groups is fine, but its basically just a quotient of a direct product by a common (central) subgroup, so probably better not to stress too much about it.

Comment: very helpful Jack, thank you. I haven't used any math software yet, but hope to investigate this in 2014. if you don't mind having a look, I outlined the application in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616381/wanted-a-lucid-demonstration-that-these-mn-bilinear-equations-have-a-solution which also has refs to the questions where I have started to get to grips with notation. you obviously have the knowledge either to show me the way with this, or to point to where what I'm attempting has already been done. meanwhile i'll check out central products. thanks once more.

Comment: Have you expanded the acted-upon set $T_{mn}$ that David described, whose entries are only elements of group $A$, into matrices whose entries are drawn from a group algebra?  If he wants to pursue the matrix construction, this is the right way to do it, but it's an expansion.

Comment: @DavidHolden: Short version: central products and Kronecker products don't help much. Switch to "Y" to have a simpler statement of the problem. There are many counterexamples if L and R allowed to have negative entries, so you need to focus on the positive aspect.

Comment: yes its all positive reals. the algorithm blows up if there are zero entries in the data matrix, which I now understand a little better in terms of ideals of the (pseudo?)-banach algebra. but your remark about central products is "central" to identifying the need to factor out one $A$. the algorithm applies alternate row and column corrections. the differential equation can (if correctly formulated) apply both simultaneously. this sounds a bit Lie-group-ish, but like tensor products, Lie groups are slightly beyond my present level of understanding.

Comment: @DavidHolden: to be clear, there are no zero entries anywhere. Just some negatives in L, R. X,P,Q are strictly positive. A random example is X=[3,3,3;1,1,2], P=[4,4,5], Q=[9;4]. Then L=diag(1,1) and R=diag(1,1,1) identity matrices work, but so does L=diag(-1,2) and R=diag(-4,-4,5).